# How can i get value from "Span id" via BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/tr-tr/analiz/hisse/Sayfalar/sirket-karti.aspx?hisse=SASA

Above this link, there is a value of a stock price highlighted with relatively big green text. I want to extract it but I can't get that value clearly. **I only need to get the value that says "136,10".** Does anyone know how can I get it accurately?

[image]

I tried to get all span lists by writing these codes but even at this point, I couldn't get any value.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import feedparser
import time


url = ("https://www.isyatirim.com.tr/tr-tr/analiz/hisse/Sayfalar/sirket-karti.aspx?hisse=SASA")
get = requests.get(url)
content = get.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
titles = soup.find_all("span")
print(titles)
```

Comment: I tried this link with `requests` but nothing returned. Also, I tried with `selenium` and it returns the price value. You can use `selenium` instead of `requests and bs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
   value = soup.find('span', {'id': 'xyz'}).get('value')
except Exception as e:
   print("Got unhandled exception %s" % str(e))
```